# Creating a group of jsx controls dynamically on the click of a button

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react page. If I click on remove button I want the
three input(school name, school address, year) to be removed from the page
and If i click on add more button the three input(school name, school address, year)
should be added as a group. The user can enter up to 3 records maximum meaning there
can exist 3 groups of (schoolname,schooladdress,year) on the page.

Here is my codesandbox

```
    https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-sanderson-fuz8o
```

Here is the link to what I was following to do this.

```
    https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-fields-with-class-z65gn
```

Quesition : How can i do this such that when i click on the add more button
the three input boxes are duplicated/dynamically created and when I click on remove
button, the 3 input boxes tied to that row are removed.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. What you want is already happening in the codesandbox.

Comment: I just noticed that. sorry about that. There is a problem though. Anything I type in the school name input shows up in the school address input. This is not correct

Comment: I made some changes maybe you can refer to it and work the code to suit your needs https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-heisenberg-o0ouz

Comment: That is because you don't have separate tracking for name and address. You do not need value tag for input, just store the school name in state onChange. May be below can help:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bartik-b37bl

Answer (score 0):

Your application should consist out of a component that manages the creation and deletion of the records and a component that manages the internal state (content of the input fields).

You probably want to exclude the create button from your records, since the action is not related to a specific record.

To remove a record you would need to pass a function as a prop to each record component and call that function inside the record container whenever the button is clicked.